# Planning to give a gift from team to a team mate

Tags: verbs

Is the below sentence correct.

Planning to present Mary for her wedding.

Educate me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As a sentence *fragment*, "planning to present Mary for her wedding" *could* be correct (but probably doesn't mean what you intend).  As a *full sentence*, is is definitely ungrammatical.

"Planning" is either an incomplete participle verb or a gerund.  Assuming it's meant to be the verb, it requires an auxiliary copula and a subject.  Put these rules together,and we get something like "**We are** planning to present Mary for her wedding".  If, on the other hand, "planning" is a gerund being used as the name of your team, you *still* need an auxiliary copula: "Planning **is** to present Mary for her wedding" - and it would be clearer still to use a noun-phrase like "the planning team" and change to the future tense: "the planning team will present Mary for her wedding".  However, none of these options means what you appear to intend; we need to make some more changes, because they still use the wrong verb.

"To present" does not mean "to give a present" but is closer in meaning to "to give **as** a present".

You could say "we are planning to give Mary a present for her wedding", or "our team will present Mary with [something] for her wedding", or "we will present [something] to Mary for her wedding".  These are full sentences, which mean that you (collectively) are going to give [something] to Mary as a wedding present.